# Search Filter Logic on Select Tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp, jstl

This is how my screen looks like.

[image: Screen Snap]

I want to use the **Search** text field to search across the list. I am unable to develop any logic for the same as the list is in the form of a select. Please let me know.

```
           <c:forEach items="${listUnallocatedpermission}" var="permisssion">
                <option value="${permisssion.perm_id}"> ${permisssion.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
       </select>
```

Comment: Did you tried any thing to achieve above ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an even listener for the search box and get the typed value. For every key stroke, you will get the value and filter all names in your permission array that includes the typed value and then refresh the list with the filtered values